# Rewrite a dynamic url after extension removed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've been working on my HTAccess for a couple days now, and I've hit a dead end.

I've rewritten and redirected the files to be extensionless, now I need to rewrite the url to be SEO Friendly.

Previously, the URL was: `http://www.example.com/member.php?playername=encodedName` 
I removed the extension: `http://www.example.com/member?playername=encodedName` 
I can't quite get it to: `http://www.example.com/member/encodedName`

Here's what I've gotten so far:

> #### Code trying to redirect to SEO Friendly URL.  Does NOT work.

```
 RewriteRule ^member/([^/]*)$ /member.php?playername=$1 [L] 
 RewriteRule ^squad/([^/]*)$ /squad.php?squadname=$1 [L] 
 RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?articlename=$1 [L]
```

> #### Unless directory, remove trailing slash. Works.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

> #### Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls. Works.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

> #### Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url. Works.

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?  It's probably a very newbie problem that I just haven't encountered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**Code trying to redirect to SEO Friendly URL**" part looks fine. And while you're redirecting requests made directly to php files to remove the extension, you're not doing anything specifically about the 3 SEO friendly URLs that you are rewriting back.

If when you go to `http://www.example.com/member/encodedName`, and you're not being served the content at `http://www.example.com/member.php?playername=encodedName`, then this looks like a Multiviews problem. You'll need to turn off Multiviews either in your server/vhost config or add this to the top of the htaccess file (or in the appropriate already existing `Options` statement):

```
Options -Multiviews
```

In order to do the redirecting **to** the SEO friendly URLs, add this *before* the "**Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url.**" rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /member\.php\?playername=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /member/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /squad\.php\?squadname=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /squad/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /artcile\.php\?articlename=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! :)